# MongoDB "error command line: unknown option setParameter" when turning on textSearchEnabled

Tags: mongodb, full-text-search

I'm trying to experiment with mongoDB's new full text search:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/enable-text-search/

However, when I either use the parameter in the mongod command, or in a config file, I get the following error:

```
[root@bobby etc]# /usr/bin/mongod --dbpath /home/bobby/data/ --setParameter textSearchEnabled=true 
error command line: unknown option setParameter use --help for help
```

And I'm running the latest version of MongoDB on Scientific Linux

```
[root@bobby etc]# mongo 
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.3 
connecting to: test
```

Interestingly, setParameter isn't listed in --help either:

```
[root@bobby etc]# /usr/bin/mongod --help | grep setParameter
(nothing)
```

Comment: in one case you said 'mongo' but in the other case you said /usr/bin/mongod - I'm guessing those two are NOT in the same place.  Try 'which mongo'  and compare to '/usr/bin/mongod --version'

Comment: Aha! `db version v2.2.3`. But `yum install mongo-10gen` gives `Package mongo-10gen-2.4.3-mongodb_1.x86_64 already installed and latest version`. Why isn't the /usr/bin/mongod updating...?

Comment: Ah, `yum install mongo-10gen-server.x86_64` fixes this.

Answer (score 0):

It was because `yum` was only updating mongo, not mongo-server.

So I used the command:

```
yum install mongo-10gen-server.x86_64
```

And now everything works :)